# Haskell GHC 7.2.2 Configure Does Not Find HsColour

Tags: haskell

Mac OSX 10.7.2, XCode 4.1, GHC 7.0.3

I am trying to build GHC 7.2.2 from source.  Here is the result of ./configure:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Configure completed successfully.

   Building GHC version  : 7.2.2

   Build platform        : x86_64-apple-darwin
   Host platform         : x86_64-apple-darwin
   Target platform       : x86_64-apple-darwin

   Bootstrapping using   : /usr/bin/ghc
      which is version   : 7.0.3

   Using GCC             : /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
      which is version   : 4.2.1

   ld       : /usr/bin/ld
   Happy    : /usr/bin/happy (1.18.6)
   Alex     : /usr/bin/alex (2.3.5)
   Python   : /opt/local/bin/python
   Perl     : /opt/local/bin/perl
   dblatex  : 
   xsltproc : /usr/bin/xsltproc

   HsColour was not found; documentation will not contain source links

   Building DocBook HTML documentation : NO
   Building DocBook PS documentation   : NO
   Building DocBook PDF documentation  : NO
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

HsColour was not found.  If I run ghc-pkg on my GHC 7.0.3 installation, it shows "hscolour-1.19" installed in the global GHC directory.  I would like source links in the documentation, so why is it not seeing hscolour?

Comment: Is HsColour in the PATH (does which find it)?

Comment: Ah!  Correct.  The executable is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HsColour is a library and executable.  It probably looked for the *executable* while you are talking about the *library*.  Be sure to install the `HsColour` executable somewhere in the current PATH.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be my mistake.  I assumed that cabal install would build and install the executable.  Seeing that this is not the case, is there any convenient method of build the executable of HsColour?

Comment: I see now that cabal has indeed built the executable, but simply has not added it to the PATH.  I found the executable in /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.0.3/lib/hscolour-1.19/bin